# get rowID value to view or edit row in different page phpGrid

Tags: php, get, grid, return-value, edit

I am new to phpGrid.

I have added new virtual column on my table that called 'Action' and it contains of 2 buttons: View and Edit for each row.

How can I get the value of the ID for that row to pass it to the next page (eg. page2.php)?

Here's the code:

```
$dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM orders", "orderNumber", "orders");

// change column titles
$dg -> set_col_title("orderNumber", "Order No.");
$dg -> set_col_title("orderDate", "Order Date");
$dg -> set_col_title("shippedDate", "Shipped Date");
$dg -> set_col_title("customerNumber",  "Customer No.");

// creating a virtual column
$col_formatter = <<<COLFORMATTER
function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){ 
return '<input type="button" value="View" onclick="window.location='page2.php?OrderNO=...'">'; 
} 
COLFORMATTER;

$dg->add_column('action', array('name'=>'action', 'index'=>'action', 'width'=>'200', 'align'=>'center', 
    'formatter'=>$col_formatter), 'Action');

$dg -> display();
```

I need to fill the dots (......) with the parameter I can pass, so the next page (page2.php) can get the parameter with $_GET['OrderNo'];

A piece of coding will be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

*Solution by OP.*

add this to the colformatter function:

```
var orderNo = parseInt(rowObject[0]);
```

and the orderNo variable is the parameter I'd been searching for.

Answer (score 0):

you could do some thing like `www.example.com/page2.php?OrderNo=12`

Comment: it's a dynamic table, so I need something like "$result['orderNumber'];" rather than exact number.

Comment: if you are using the data base table then you could get the primary key and pass it. Otherwise you could use a counter variable to find the row number which is clicked and pass it

Comment: I edited my question so you guys can see the coding and maybe know what code should I use to get the primary key parameter. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$dg->add_column('action', array('name'=>'act', 'index'=>'action', 'width'=>'200', 'align'=>'center', 
'formatter'=>$col_formatter), 'Action');


use 'name'=>'act'
```